# What are the signs of an old cat dying?

Tags: cats, eating, weight-loss

She is a 17 year old female indoor cat. I have only had her for almost 7 years. She's always loved food, but she began turning her nose up to even her favorites. About a week later, she isn't eating even a tablespoon of food in a day. She was drinking water but today had none in almost 24 hours. She stays in a corner in my bedroom where it's dark. She has never slept there before.

If I take her to a vet, I can't go in because of the coronavirus. I don't want to leave her there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to take her to the vet, whether you can go in or not. Not eating and drinking can be dangerous within 48 hours. We cannot diagnose her over the internet.

Comment: Your concern for how your cat will be treated without you there with her is understandable - make those concerns clearly known when you check your cat into the vet.

Comment: Cats tend to hide (from predators) when not feeling well. Your cat hiding in a dark corner where she doesn't normally hang out sounds like this behavior. Just another indicator that all is not well. Please take her to the vet.

Comment: I joined just to say my cat had to be put to sleep just a few weeks ago, he had the exact same symptoms, plus he was throwing up a lot. His kidneys had shut down and the vets felt they could not recover. Please take your can to the vet asap!

Answer (score 45):

This is an emergency, so you need to get her to the vet.

If a cat stops eating for more than 24 hours it can cause fatty liver syndrome; this might be fatal in itself. And the illness that is the cause for not eating must be solved as fast as possible or your cat will die.

You need to call your vet to find the closest emergency veterinary service; where I live the vets are still open for emergencies but not for the regular services.

Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feline_hepatic_lipidosis

This answer was made during the covid lockdown,most veterinary services have resumed normal operation by now.

Comment: I'm currently at the vet. Some won't let you in the building but will take your pet in, calling you for updates and authorizations.

Comment: When our old cat stopped eating, he had a cancer in his mouth/throat that made it painful for him to do so. Definitely agree with the "get her to the vet immediately", just posting another possible reason.

Comment: In the US (at least in Chicago) the pandemic is still going on. My vet has a taped area customers are asked to stand outside. They talked with me about treatments afterwards. (My 17 year old also hadn't eaten for a day. He had an infection. They gave him antibiotics and fluids.)

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest palliative care.  Make your cat comfortable.  Set up a warm place with a comfortable soft nest.  If it likes your presence, touch it, hold it, help it feel secure.

My wife's old cat died in her arms a few years ago.  The cat passed quietly, and she felt great connection with him.

At 17, there a limit to the troubles you'll want to give your cat to extend its life a smidgeon more.  The most likely outcome will be euthanasia.  A cat's home death need not be "difficult", and can be an easier transition for both you and your cat.